# ActionScript 3 - accessing variable on root not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, root, event-listener, dispatchevent

I have a variable (String) frame 1 scene 1 called 'test'. I also have a movieclip called 'pointerMC'. Inside pointerMC, I have another movieclip called handMC. Inside handMC, I want to dispatch an event like so:

```
root.dispatchEvent(new Event("eventName"));
```

except I want "eventName" to be the 'test' variable which holds a string, so something like this:

```
root.dispatchEvent(new Event(root.test));
```

but when I do this, it gives an error saying:

```
Symbol 'handMC', Layer 'actions', Frame 20, Line 2  1119: Access of possibly undefined property test through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
root.dispatchEvent(new Event(MovieClip(root).test));
```

worked.